# Why is my clear pex tubing turning red/brown?

Tags: pex

I am noticing that the pex tubing in my home ( at the supply line) is turning to a brownish/reddish color.  The color fades as it spans out ( after 8ft or so) Is this normal or is this something that I should be concern about?  Please advise.

Comment: Almost certainly from rust in the pipes outside your house.

Answer (score 1):

Areas that have high iron in the water will cause iron scale to build up on the inside of the pipe. Other possible causes if on city water is metal water pipe in the supply. Over time it may get darker and is not unusual. In the past it was not visible because the pipe was not transparent like PEX.